# How to add gradient fill on bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, bar-chart, fill

I have data frame (`df`), with column: `asdfg` (character) and `NUMERIC` (numeric).

Using

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = asdfg, y = NUMERIC)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill= "red")
```

I made something like that:

[image]

Now I want to get bar chart like:

[image]

I've no idea how to do that. I've tried using `scale_colour_gradient2` but it doesn't work (probably I did it wrong).

Comment: according to which variable do you want to fill your bars?

Comment: according to NUMERIC (greater value = darker color)

Comment: `geom_bar` aggregates the data in the `asdfg` column, so it's not possible to reasonably refer these values to the ones in the column `NUMERIC`, unless they are identical for each value in the column `asdfg`

Comment: in which case you can fill them according to the `..count..` variable which is generated by the `stat_bin` statistic

Comment: column NUMERIC consists of mean values of a, s, d, f, g. 

is it a way to fill it like I want?

Or maybe different way to draw that bar chart and then fill it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
# generate sample data - you have this already
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(asdfg=unlist(strsplit("asdfg","")),NUMERIC=sample(1:5,5))

# you start here..
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = asdfg, y = NUMERIC, fill=NUMERIC)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#FF8888",high="#FF0000")
```

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds! +1

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly how it supposed to look like